# Passing through a parameter to document.getElementById when using it in Nightmare evaluate()

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, nightmare

I am trying to run my `checkPrice` function with parameters that I pass in:

```
const nightmare = require('nightmare')()

let url = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/Guards-Discworld-City-Watch-Collection/dp/1473200180/"
let identifier = "price"

checkPrice(url, identifier)

async function checkPrice(url2, identifier2) {
    console.log(identifier2)
    const priceString = await nightmare.goto(url2)
        .wait(`#${identifier2}`)
        .evaluate(() => document.getElementById(identifier2).innerText)
        .end()
    console.log(priceString)
    console.log("Hello!")
}
```

The problem that I'm getting is that I keep getting "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: identifier2 is not defined".

If I change the `document.getElementById(identifier2).innerText)` to `document.getElementById("price").innerText)` then it works fine.

Is there any way to pass through a parameter to `getElementById()` in the way I am trying to do?

I have tried putting in a hardcoded value for `identifier2` which did work but would mean I am not able to use the function in the way I was planning. I also tried using `identifier2` inside of a string (`${identifier2}`) which did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nightmare runs both a Node.js process and a browser process. The main testing code is run in the Node.js process, but Nightmare serializes the function you pass to `evaluate` and runs it in the browser process. Since they're in completely different processes, you can't just close over variables. Instead, pass the values you need into `evaluate` as subsequent arguments, and update your function signature to expect them as paramters. Here's the example showing this in [the documentation](https://github.com/segment-boneyard/nightmare#evaluatefn-arg1-arg2):

> ```
> const selector = 'h1'
> nightmare
>   .evaluate(selector => {
>     // now we're executing inside the browser scope.
>     return document.querySelector(selector).innerText
>   }, selector) // <-- that's how you pass parameters from Node scope to browser scope
>   .then(text => {
>     // ...
>   })
> ```

*(That's their code comment. Note that "scope" isn't quite the right word, but it's the general idea.)*

Adapting your code to do that:

```
async function checkPrice(url2, identifier2) {
    console.log(identifier2)
    const priceString = await nightmare.goto(url2)
        .wait(`#${identifier2}`)
        .evaluate((identifier2) => document.getElementById(identifier2).innerText, identifier2)
        //         ^^^^^^^^^^^                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        .end()
    console.log(priceString)
    console.log("Hello!")
}
```